# Estimate $\pi$ using a 3D Random Walk.

Tags: probability, random-walk, pi

[image: 3d-walk]

A [3D Random Walk](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3d%20random%20walk) according to WolframAlpha says:

$P(\text{{probability of eventual return to origin}}) = 1 - \frac{{16 \sqrt{{\frac{2}{3}}} \pi^3}}{{\Gamma(\frac{1}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{5}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{7}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{11}{24})}} \approx 0.340537$

Rearranging gives

\begin{equation*}
\pi = \left[ \frac{{0.659463 \cdot \Gamma(\frac{1}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{5}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{7}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{11}{24})}}{{16 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}} \right]^{1/3}
\end{equation*}

Plugging that equation into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%280.659463%20*%20Gamma%5B1%2F24%5D%20*%20Gamma%5B5%2F24%5D%20*%20Gamma%5B7%2F24%5D%20*%20Gamma%5B11%2F24%5D%29%20%2F%20%2816%20*%20Sqrt%5B2%2F3%5D%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29) computes $\pi$ as

$$3.1415931769021159447130538115032990978757778167518560061468225968...$$

However, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Pi) for $\pi$ is

$$3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923...$$

**Question**

Is there a way to tweak that equation to improve the accuracy of $\pi$?

Comment: You will nee more significant figures on the $0.340537$.  But I think your problem is backward.  Even that value $0.340537$ was computed by plugging in a value for $\pi$ in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the *approximation* sign in Wolfram alpha's expression
$$
1 - \frac{{16 \sqrt{{\frac{2}{3}}} \pi^3}}{{\Gamma(\frac{1}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{5}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{7}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{11}{24})}} \color{red}{\approx} 0.340537
$$
for the probability, which means you can only expect the expession
\begin{equation*}
\left[ \frac{{0.659463 \cdot \Gamma(\frac{1}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{5}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{7}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{11}{24})}}{{16 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}} \right]^{1/3}
\end{equation*}
to approximate $\ \pi\ $ to about $\ 6\ $ decimal places at the most. Plugging the expresssion
$$
a=1 - \frac{{16 \sqrt{{\frac{2}{3}}} \pi^3}}{{\Gamma(\frac{1}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{5}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{7}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{11}{24})}}
$$
[into Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1-%2816*pi%5E3*sqrt%282%2F3%29%29%2F%28Gamma%281%2F24%29*Gamma%285%2F24%29*Gamma%287%2F24%29*Gamma%2811%2F24%29%29), however, gives a much more accurate value,
$$
0.3405373295509991428262731844329028967106082171243020977632361053
$$
for $\ a\ $.  If you now submit the expression
$$
\left[ \frac{{(1-a) \cdot \Gamma(\frac{1}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{5}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{7}{24}) \Gamma(\frac{11}{24})}}{{16 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}} \right]^{1/3}
$$
[to Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%281-0.3405373295509991428262731844329028967106082171243020977632361053%29*Gamma%281%2F24%29*Gamma%285%2F24%29*Gamma%287%2F24%29*Gamma%2811%2F24%29%2F%2816*sqrt%282%2F3%29%29+%29%5E%281%2F3%29), it returns the much more accurate approximation
$$
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445924
$$
to $\ \pi\ $, differing from the value it gives for that constant only in the last of its $\ 64\ $ decimal places.